# Question regarding value assigned for an integer

Tags: java, arrays, methods

***No issue with code rather a logical question***

I would like to know why the value of n is considered 5 rather 7 in the reversed the array code block? I thought the value is 7 rather 5. to my understanding, the n value is coming from (1+2+3+4+5)/2 means 7.5 but taken as 7 in the first for loop then why it is taken as 5 in the second loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    reverse(arr, arr.length);

}

public static void reverse(int[] a, int n) {
    int i, k, temp;//threee int variable is created
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) // n value is 15/2= 7.5  here
        { temp = a[i];        
        a[i] = a[n - i - 1]; 
        a[n - i - 1] = temp;
                                
    }

    /*printing the reversed array*/
    System.out.println("Reversed array is: ");
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) // why the n value considered as 5 here? 
       { System.out.print(a[k] + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: N is array length not sum

Answer (score 1):

The n is the arr.length which is 5, cause the arr has 5 elements.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you pls tell me what is the value of n is considered in the fast forloop for two times?

Comment: In the reverse for loop the n is 5, i is defined to be int so the result is 5/2 = 2

Answer (score 1):

I think you are miss to understand what is the length of the array.

int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

this arr.length is 5 because it has 5 items. We consider the count of items as the length in the array. If you consider array length as 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 then it is wrong.